# data import error in openrowset with variable path

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i am importing my data from excel file to Sql Database using openrowset
following are my command

```
declare @path varchar(100)='E:\11.08.2017 .xlsx;'
```

`SELECT *  into palwal12 FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0; Database='+@path+' HDR=YES; IMEX=1',
'SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]')`

i successfully insert data into table while using simple query. but when if i want to use variable path to insert data then i m having an error as
incorrect syntax near '+'. 
i thought my syntax for using path variable is wrong. somebody could help me please.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use variables in openrowset parameters, they have to be string literals
What you can do is create a dynamic sql and then execute it.
example:

```
Declare @sql varchar(max) = your sql
exec(@sql)
```

Comment: thanx @jayvee with the help of your answer i finally run my query

Answer (score 0):

as @jayvee suggested me i created a dynamic Sql and execute my query as following

```
`DECLARE @sql varchar(MAX);
DECLARE @path varchar(255);
SET @path = 'E:\11.08.2017 .xlsx;'
SET @sql = 'SELECT * INTO ravan FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
  ''Excel 12.0; Database='+@path+' HDR=YES; IMEX=1'', 
  ''SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]'')';

EXEC (@sql)
```